# Unexpected result when comparing ints

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer wrapper objects share the same instances only within the value 127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/integer-wrapper-objects-share-the-same-instances-only-within-the-value-127)
>   [How != and == operators work on Integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824053/how-and-operators-work-on-integers-in-java)

I tried to compare two ints with the following cases and got unexpected results

1. when I did the following, @@@ was printed.

   ```
    class C {
      static Integer a = 127;
      static Integer b = 127;
      public static void main(String args[]){
      if(a==b){
         System.out.println("@@@"); 
      }
      }
    }
   ```
2. when I did the following, @@@ was not printed.

   ```
    class C {
      static Integer a = 145;
      static Integer b = 145;
      public static void main(String args[]){
      if(a==b){
         System.out.println("@@@"); 
      }
      }
    }
   ```

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason.

Comment: If someone could format it..I am not able to...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer wrapper objects share the same instances only within the value 127?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/integer-wrapper-objects-share-the-same-instances-only-within-the-value-127) and [New Integer vs valueOf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974561) and [Inconsistent behavior on java's ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148805) and [Integer wrapper objects share the same instances only within the value 127?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132) and...

Comment: More details if you are interested http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/surprising-results-of-autoboxing.html

Comment: hey this looks good explanation..will read it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're comparing the objects' identities. For values lower than 128 the Integer class caches its objects. That's why it is equal in the first example. The other example is with higher values that are not cached.

As @niklon pointed out there is also a lower border of -128 for caching.

Upper border can be adjusted with a VM arg `-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=4711`.

Further reading in Peter's interesting blog post:
http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/surprising-results-of-autoboxing.html

Comment: Does that happen with every other wrapper class too?

Comment: By the way, the lower bound for Integer cacheing is -128.

Comment: @niklon, This is an implementation detail.  The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) says "This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, **and may cache other values outside of this range.**"

Comment: In fact you can set the upper border to another custom value with a vm arg I think.

Comment: @PhaniRahul `Long` and `Short` have caching, too.

Answer (score 5):

You're not comparing `int`s, you're comparing objects for reference equality.  Use `.equals`, or use type `int` instead of `Object`.

Comment: /Then why is it printing "@@@" in the first case..?

Comment: @Raghav, because many versions of Java [memoize small `Integer`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29): "This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range."

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using `Integer` objects as opposed to `int` primitives. Hence, you should compare the two instances with `.equals(...)` as opposed to `==`. If you used the primitive type instead, you would use `==`.

It is important to note that, when dealing with objects, `==` compares the *references* of the two objects, not the actual values - so it may return seemingly strange results at times.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if(a.equals(b))` and do not use `==` to compare Objects that are subclasses of Object class.

`==` operator is just for primitive types like int,long, etc.